# How to add sleep setting to cron job

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

Bellow is my cron command.I want to add the sleep command there.

This is what i tried so far.is that CORRECT ?

```
* * * * *  root sleep 5 && /home/samitha/bash.sh >> /home/samitha/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is absolutely correct. You can also use `;` instead of `&&`, but in this case it doesn't matter because `sleep` returns 0 always.

**Update**

This format here is for `/etc/crontab`.

If you use users' crontabs (edit them using crontab -e, as on the screenshot),
you must omit username from the line:

```
* * * * *  sleep 5 && /home/samitha/bash.sh >> /home/samitha/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Comment: why it's required root ?

Comment: That is format of crontab. In /etc/crontab you must specify a user, priveleges of that will be used to run the command. If you add this command to users' crontab you must remove this field.

Comment: Now my script doesn't run ?

Comment: i added the screenshot of crontab in ubuntu ?tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: You use `crontab -e`. In this case you should omit the username. See my update

Answer (score 1):

example: To execute command every 1min with random between 1..5 seconds

```
*/1 * * * *  sleep $(((RANDOM \% 5) + 1)); yourCommand
```